# UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum not finding the file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, alassetslibrary

I am trying to cleanup the deprecated warnings and having trouble with migrating from

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
if([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:srcURL]) {
    ...
```

to

```
if(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(srcURL.absoluteString)) {
    ...
```

with both the same

```
NSURL *srcURL = ...
```

The first call works fine, but the second one gives me the following output in the console and returns false.

```
Video file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8149A5B8-11EA-41E6-B1A7-2CCAABDE5E35/tmp/tempAudio.mov cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." .......
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `srcURL.absoluteString` with `srcURL.path`.

`UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum()` expects a path, so the parameter value should not include a scheme like `file://`.